# Android Telegram , few classes not found

Tags: android, telegram

I have integrated Telegram in one of my projects, but while running it is not able to find certain classes.

Here is the exception log:

```
08-25 23:51:57.107  12517-12517/? E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-25 23:51:57.429  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.messenger.FileLog$4', referenced from method org.telegram.messenger.FileLog.d
08-25 23:51:57.430  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.messenger.FileLog$2', referenced from method org.telegram.messenger.FileLog.e
08-25 23:51:57.430  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.messenger.FileLog$1', referenced from method org.telegram.messenger.FileLog.e
08-25 23:51:57.431  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.messenger.FileLog$3', referenced from method org.telegram.messenger.FileLog.e
08-25 23:51:57.432  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.messenger.FileLog$5', referenced from method org.telegram.messenger.FileLog.w
08-25 23:51:57.435  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.android.time.FastDateFormat$1', referenced from method org.telegram.android.time.FastDateFormat.<clinit>
08-25 23:51:57.436  12517-12517/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'org.telegram.android.time.FastDatePrinter', referenced from method org.telegram.android.time.FastDateFormat.<init>
08-25 23:51:57.512  12517-12517/? A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 12517 (com.bcd.paidapp)
```

Here is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bcd.paidapp"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':pullToRefreshLi')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0'
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.6.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-plus-v1-1.3.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.6.0-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/quickblox-android-1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-media-support-3.0.2.jar')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':TMessagesProj')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.8.2.jar')
}
```

Any idea guys ?

Thanks